# How to run code on ASP.NET SERVER (or any) without client interaction?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, server, cloud, client-server

I have made a WPF Desktop application that fetches data from an API (on every launch) provided by the website over the Internet and updates its UI accordingly. Now I want to change that. I want to put the application's fetching functionality on the cloud which regularly gets data from API and store it in a SQL SERVER (or any) database. Now I want the application on the client side to get data from the database and not from the API itself (can be on every launch or when there is a change in data).

**WHATS THE PROBLEM THEN ?**

- When thinking of a desktop application over the cloud on a windows virtual machine it feels ok and I understand how to implement it.
- But when thinking of a web application the server is supposed to respond to client request and then perform some piece of code to give output/Response. Which I don't need I wan't the code to just run weekly or monthly without client asking.

**WHAT I WANT ?**

I wan't the server to up 24/7 and updating the database every week.
How usually such kind of thing is implemented in general. Let say for example stack overflow. Don't they perform certain task independent  of the client on their servers.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to run background jobs? Like scheduled tasks?

Comment: If that means any piece of code that does not depend on client requesting a specific URL, then yes.

Comment: So you want some code to be always running in the cloud? Or to execute at specific times in the cloud, without having a user need to manually invoke it? Sure, there's ways of doing that. Service applications are designed to run all the time, and most cloud providers have ways to host services. Those services can have schedulers built into them. Or there's ways with some cloud providers to invoke code on a schedule. You'll need to pick a cloud provider and then research your options.

Comment: Keep in mind, you really should not have desktop applications directly accessing a database. Desktop applications should talk to a service (such as Web API or WCF), which will interact with the database on their behalf.

Comment: I need to do both (Always running and on specific times) . Lets assume the cloud is my own pc as well (a.k.a localhost ) and the client is another PC in my house connected via LAN. Then how using pure ASP.NET ?

Comment: The cloud can't be on your PC. That goes against the fundamental definition of what the cloud is. You'll need to create a service that's always running then, and then host it either on a server or in the cloud.

Comment: I see where I got confused I really need a service then, Can you refer me some resources form where I can achieve my goal. Will I create it via ASP.NET or some other way ?

Comment: There's lots of ways. Stack Overflow isn't here to find tutorials for you. You'll need to learn to use the resources at your disposal to find information about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll see what I can find.